# Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) driver for Broadcom Corp BCM 4352 Wireless Network Adapter

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, dell, broadcom

I've recently purchased a Dell Alienware 17 laptop and I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (kernel = 3.11.0-15) on it.

The problem is that the wireless card (Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)) doesn't work in my Linux installation.
 I see that the drivers Dell offers on its website (http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/driverdetails?driverid=W49DT) are all for Windows.

Broadcom's Linux drivers (http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php) are only for the BCM4311-, BCM4312-, BCM4313-, BCM4321-, BCM4322-, BCM43224-, and BCM43225-, BCM43227- and BCM43228-based hardware (and not for the BCM4352 hardware that I have) and supported till kernel 3.8.x (mine is 3.11.0.15).

I notice that Dell now sells Alienware machines with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on them and must have a driver for this card. Where can I access that and how do I go about installing it?

Comment: Please edit you question to add details of the wireless device from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280  Thanks.

Comment: I have a Dell Precision M4800 and it looks like this.        03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03) .  I think there are not YET working linux drivers for the BCM4352.

Comment: Could you please tell which header has to be installed, because for after any header installation BCM kernel is giving error. TIA
Harish Babu

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem with my precision m4800. I found the DELL Ubuntu driver package which worked for me here :

[M4800_M6800_A03.fish.tar.gz](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=53R21&fileId=3333875845&osCode=1204A&productCode=precision-m4800-workstation&languageCode=EN&categoryId=CS)

I un-tared the file looked in the "debs" directory and found the kernel for the bcm 4352 (or dell 1550 as they brand it)

Make sure you install the headers in the /debs/main directory first and it should be as simple as double clicking to install. You might want to restart after installing the package and blacklisting any of the other broadcom drivers you might have installed whilst testing

This is what I installed :

```
/debs/bcmwl-kernel-source-dw1550.deb
/debs/bt-dw1550-firmware_0.1_all.deb
```

Good luck!

Edit:
On Ubuntu 14.04 you can also simply do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but I am using Ubuntu 14.10. Is it safe to install these deb files on Ubuntu 14.10?

Comment: I have bcmwl-kernel-source. I assume I have to build and install it. Procedure?