# Wifi broadcom BCM4352 not recognized after fresh install

Tags: broadcom

I've run a live USB session on Ubuntu 14.10 before installing it. In software & Updates -> Additional Drivers I could directly select a Broadcom proprietary driver. After a click on Apply Changes, the wifi went on.
Now I've installed Ubuntu for real (updating the packages during the installation process), I can still see the Broadcom driver displayed, but selecting it fails.

I've seen in other threads that people tried some complex solutions that eventually worked ([BCM4352 Wireless network card issues with lubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474930/bcm4352-wireless-network-card-issues-with-lubuntu-14-04-lts)).

Before trying this, do you have any idea why something would work on a live session and not a installed system ? I really wish there was a simple solution to my problem (I'm quite new with Linux). Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to enable the wifi on my dell xps 15 (2015) on Ubuntu 14.10.

Here is my personal complete process:

- Boot on a live disk.
- Go to Software & Updates, Additional Drivers, select the Broadcom one and Apply Changes. Wifi should work on the live session.
- Then launch an Install of Ubuntu from the live session (eventually erasing your previous install).
- Allow third-party softwares to be installed, and check the "download updates" option.
- Restart.
- Now, in the freshly installed ubuntu, I couldn't select the broadcom driver anymore and wifi was down.
- I downloaded the driver from here on another PC:
  http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/admin/bcmwl-kernel-source
  And put in on a USB stick.
- On my dell I simply double-clicked on it and the ubuntu software center installed it. And I had the joy to see the wifi wake up :)

Answer (score 3):

1. After you install Ubuntu to your hard drive, you can extract `bcmwl-kernel-source` and its dependency `dkms` from the install DVD or USB.
2. Navigate to `/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl` and drag and drop the deb file to your desktop.
3. Next, navigate to `/pool/main/d/dkms` drag and drop `dkms` to your desktop.
4. Now install both with:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i ~/Desktop/*.deb
   ```
5. Load the driver:

   ```
   sudo modprobe wl
   ```

Your wireless should now be working.