# BCM4352 offical dell driver installation problem

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, dell, broadcom

I've downloaded dell ubuntu 12.04 drivers and un-tar the package. Then enter the approprite folder to install as specified in first and one answer this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432933/linux-ubuntu-12-04-driver-for-broadcom-corp-bcm-4352-wireless-network-adapter). First i've installed it with double clicking and it gave an error after that removed it and install on terminal again and it gave the same error again.
Terminal output;

```
root@dell-p-m4800:/media/DATA/Linux - Yedek/M4800_M6800_A03.fish.tar/M4800_M6800_A03.fish/debs# dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source-dw1550.deb
Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
(Reading database ... 467738 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (from bcmwl-kernel-source-dw1550.deb) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.64somerville1) ...
Loading new bcmwl-kernel-source-6.30.223.64somerville1 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.13.0-35-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.13.0-35-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.13.0-35-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.64somerville1/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing bcmwl-kernel-source (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bcmwl-kernel-source
```

make.log file;

```
DKMS make.log for bcmwl-kernel-source-6.30.223.64somerville1 for kernel 3.13.0-35-generic (x86_64)
Tue Sep  2 22:42:24 EEST 2014
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-35-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.64somerville1/build modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-35-generic'
CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
Using CFG80211 API
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.64somerville1/build/src/shared/linux_osl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.64somerville1/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.64somerville1/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_tkip_printstats’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.64somerville1/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:3237:7: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘wl->tkipmodops->print_stats’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
       wl->tkip_bcast_data[idx]);
       ^
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.64somerville1/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:3237:7: note: expected ‘struct seq_file *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.64somerville1/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:3240:4: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘wl->tkipmodops->print_stats’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    wl->tkipmodops->print_stats(debug_buf, wl->tkip_ucast_data);
    ^
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.64somerville1/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:3240:4: note: expected ‘struct seq_file *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.64somerville1/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_reg_proc_entry’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.64somerville1/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:3461:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘create_proc_entry’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  if ((wl->proc_entry = create_proc_entry(tmp, 0644, NULL)) == NULL) {
  ^
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.64somerville1/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:3461:22: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  if ((wl->proc_entry = create_proc_entry(tmp, 0644, NULL)) == NULL) {
                      ^
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.64somerville1/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:3466:16: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  wl->proc_entry->read_proc = wl_proc_read;
                ^
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.64somerville1/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:3467:16: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  wl->proc_entry->write_proc = wl_proc_write;
                ^
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.64somerville1/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:3468:16: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  wl->proc_entry->data = wl;
                ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.64somerville1/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.64somerville1/build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-35-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

there are some pointer or type errors as far as I am concerned. How can I fix this problem? Must I change the code? Or is this a kernel version problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a mismatch between the kernel version and the bcmwl-kernel-source version provided by Dell. I would suggest you try the official Ubuntu version in the repositories. With a temporary working internet connection:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If this does not work, then do:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Download this package to your desktop: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb

Install it with:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Desktop/bcmwl*.deb
sudo modprobe wl
```

Comment: thanks @chili555 I did what you said but when I rebooted pc it lags on the ubuntu typed purple window and it didn't close I forced it to close by holdling the power buton then opened it (nothing was working). After these it shows me the same software installation error  about bcmwl-kernel-source and wifi still does not working

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: I removed bcmwl-kernel-source, downloaded other one and install with dpkg but after the install on terminal; 'code' DKMS: Install Completed 'code' still no other response from terminal, Control didn't turn to user on terminal, is this normal?

Comment: Yes, it is. After a reboot, is there any wireless?

Comment: yes there is. I need reboot now and then sudo modprobe wl?

Comment: Thank you so much @chili555 I'm not signing the answer useful because I haven't got enough rep. Wireless driver installed and working finding all the connections around. But now it is not accept my wireless password -_- . Probably it's not about the driver or installation. Thank you so much again.