# Connected to network, but browser will not load pages...most of the time FIXED

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, broadcom

I found a work around. I had an old router laying around from before I had comcast. So I plugged it in to my comcast modem/router, and my desktop likes that network well enough. Not the coolest solution, but it works just fine.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Lenovo desktop. Internet used to work fine on it. We got a new cable modem from Comcast, and now I'm having issues with my network connection.

My computer has a connection. `ifconfig` gives me this for wlan0:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:cf:5e:03:98:85
          inet addr:10.0.0.18  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2601:1:8780:39bd:6098:c36d:54fa:af47/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::1acf:5eff:fe03:9885/64 Scope/Link
          inet6 addr: 2601:1:8780:39bd:1acf:5eff:fe03:9885/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  METRIC:1
          RX packets:75821 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:3479897
          TX packets:37624 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:27066662 (27.0 MB)  TX bytes:4137161 (4.1 MB)
          Interrupt:17
```

I've pinged www.google.com, www.msn.com, as well as my default gateway 10.0.0.1, usually with 100% success.

I also changed the DNS server to be 8.8.8.8, and made my IP static. The modem and my desktop have been restarted many times

However, 99% of the time, if I try to access a webpage, the browser just hangs while it's trying to connect. Occasionally, I'll get a brief window where I can browse normally for maybe 30-60 seconds.

`lspci` says my wireless adapter is a Broadcom BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless network adapter

Thanks in advance

I disabled ipv6 on my machine like user68186 suggested. Did not resolve the problem though. And according to this faq: http://www.comcast6.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=45  ipv6 cannot be disabled on a comcast modem/router.

Comment: There is no such thing as Ubuntu 14.01. You probably mean Ubuntu 14.04 or Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: I tried it, but that didn't resolve it. Is there a way that I could make my computer more ipv6 compatible?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/519308/bcm4352-offical-dell-driver-installation-problem